# create tree from list of list c#

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, tree

I have an issue creating a treee from a list of list of string.
Here my input data :

```
    IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<string>> listeDesParcours = new List<IReadOnlyList<string>>
    {
        new List<string>
        {
            "Produit","Sinistre","Particulier","Auto","RC"
        },
        new List<string>
        {
            "Produit","Sinistre","Entreprise","Auto","2roues"
        },
        new List<string>
        {
            "Produit","reclamation","Particulier","Moto","PP"
        },
        new List<string>
        {
            "Produit","reclamation","Entreprise","Auto","TT"
        },
        new List<string>
        {
            "Produit","reclamation","Entreprise","Auto","PP"
        },
        new List<string>
        {
            "Produit","souscription","Salarie","Aviation"
        },
        new List<string>
        {
            "Produit","souscription","Salarie","Aviation","Airbus"
        },
        new List<string>
        {
            "Produit","reclamation","Reclamation tout court"
        },
        new List<string>
        {
            "Produit","Produit tout court"
        },
        new List<string>
        {
            "Produit","Sinistre","Entreprise","Auto","5roues"
        }
    };
```

As you can see, its a list of list of string and i want to get a tree from it 
.
here is my object that i want to return in the end

```
 public class Node
        {
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public List<Node> Childs { get; set; }
        }
```

and this is how i want to get the structure

```
                                 RootElement
                                      |
        ___________________________Produit__________________________
       /                             |                              \
__sinistre___________          reclamation_______                 Souscription
|                   \               /            \                     |           
entreprise      particulier      entreprise   particulier            Salarie______________
    |               |                |            |                       |               \
   auto            auto             auto        auto                    Marine             Aviation__
                                                                                              /      \
                                                                                           Airbus  Boing
```

Can anyone point me please to a recursive method that allows me to fill the tree from the list of list please?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT** :
After the last comment i want to clarify that i want to get the object of type Node that i created ... however my Input is the list of list of string

Comment: hi ! Can you accept a non recursive method if it solves your problem?

Comment: @KarouiHaythem yes if i can get the object as described ofcourse it would be great ! :)

Comment: I didn't quite get if you want to use your own structure or want to use standard List of lists

Comment: @t.m. my input, as mentioned, is a list of list, and i want to return an object of type Node that i created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var root = new Node() { Value = "RootElement", Childs = new List<Node>() };
    foreach (var route in listeDesParcours)
    {
        var current = root;
        foreach (var value in route)
        {
            var child = current.Childs.Find(x => x.Value == value);
            if (child == null)
            {
                child = new Node() { Value = value, Childs = new List<Node>() };
                current.Childs.Add(child);
            }
            current = child;
        }
    }
```

Note that there's some difference between the data in `listeDesParcours` and the drawn tree, so the resulting tree in `root` doesn't look *exactly* like yours.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the rootNode that will be returned.
2. Write a function like 

   `populateRootNode(Node rootNode, IReadOnlyList> input)`

   In this function, create nodes 
   for each list, an add crated nodes to children of rootNode. And call addChildrenNodes(see 3) for each List.
3. Write a function like 
   `addChildrenNodes(Node ParentNode, List input)`.

   In this function, create nodes for each item of given list and add created nodes as children of current node.
4. Return the rootNode

Comment: This is not a recursive method, because the input is not a tree of uniform nodes.